# missing required keys: [:id]というエラーで困っています。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

## やりたいこと

ダミーページからlink_toを使い、purchase_product_pathのページに
いきたいのですが、エラーが出てしまい上手くいきません。

もし、解決方法などがわかる方がいらしゃいましたら
ご教授をお願い出来ないでしょうか？

## 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Products#index
Showing /Users/apple/projects/fleamarket_sample_73e/app/views/products/index.html.haml where line #1 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"purchase", :controller=>"products"}, missing required keys: [:id]

=============================================================================================
= link_to purchase_product_path do  #こちらの行がExtracted sourceです
  .furima__logo--dami
    = image_tag src="material/logo/logo.png", size: "135x35"
```

## 該当するコード

routes.rb

```
  resources :products do
    collection do
      get 'get_category_children',      defaults: { format: 'json' }
      get 'get_category_grandchildren', defaults: { format: 'json' }
    end
    member do
      get 'purchase', to: 'products#purchase'
    end
  end
```

products_controller.rb

```
  def purchase
  end
```

rails routesをすると下のようになります。

```
et_category_grandchildren_products GET    /products/get_category_grandchildren(.:format)                                           products#get_category_grandchildren {:format=>"json"}
                   purchase_product GET    /products/:id/purchase(.:format)                                                         products#purchase
                           products GET    /products(.:format)                                                                      products#index
                                    POST   /products(.:format)                                                                      products#create
                        new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)                                                                  products#new
                       edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)                                                             products#edit
                            product GET    /products/:id(.:format)                                                                  products#show
                                    PATCH  /products/:id(.:format)                                                                  products#update
                                    PUT    /products/:id(.:format)                                                                  products#update
                                    DELETE /products/:id(.:format)                                                                  products#destroy
```

railsで自分のアプリを作ろうとした時に起きた問題です。

「idが渡されていない」という事が問題だと思うのですが、「pathにid」を渡す
処理がないてこと？と考えていますが、に具体的に自分がどのようにしてコードを書き処理ができる
のか検討が付かなかったので、投稿させていただきました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 時間も経っているので恐らく別のユーザーでしょうが、[teratail で全く同じタイトルの質問と回答](https://teratail.com/questions/234900) がヒットしますので参考までに。(私自身は Rails について詳しくないのでコメントに留めます)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。そちらをteratail 参考にして作ったので、文言がかなり似っております。紛らわしくして申し訳ありません先ほど、再度見直してやり直しました。こちらのエラーは、何とか直りましたが違うエラーが出で詰まっております。何とか乗り越えたいと思います。ご回答ありがとうございました